# SFML extremly slow/irregular framerate

Tags: c++, sfml

I've recently been on the lookout for a C++ game-developement framework and decided to give SFML a try. I've implemented an early example from the book 'SFML game developement' to see if things work properly. Sadly they don't.

The code is supposed to make a circular object move rapidly when pressing one of the 'wasd' keys. In reality the circle begins moving slowly for a distance of maybe ten pixels, then stops and if I hold the respective key down further the circle jumps another few pixels whenever it feels like it.

```
//the header game.h
class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    void run();

private:
    void processEvents();
    void handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key, bool);
    void update();
    void render();

    sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
    sf::CircleShape mPlayer;

    bool mIsMovingUp;
    bool mIsMovingDown;
    bool mIsMovingLeft;
    bool mIsMovingRight;
};

//the implementation
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "game.h"

Game::Game()
: mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application")
, mIsMovingUp(false), mIsMovingDown(false), mIsMovingLeft(false), mIsMovingRight(false)
, mPlayer()
{
    mPlayer.setRadius(40.f);
    mPlayer.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    mPlayer.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
}

void Game::run()
{
    while (mWindow.isOpen())
    {
        processEvents();
        update();
        render();
    }
}

void Game::render() 
{
    mWindow.clear();
    mWindow.draw(mPlayer);
    mWindow.display();
}

void Game::processEvents()
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (mWindow.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, true);
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
                handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, false);
                break;
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                mWindow.close();
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Game::handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed)
{
    if (key == sf::Keyboard::W)
            mIsMovingUp = isPressed;

    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::S)
            mIsMovingDown = isPressed;

    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::A)
            mIsMovingLeft = isPressed;

    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::D)
            mIsMovingRight = isPressed;
}

void Game::update()
{
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.f, 0.f);

    if (mIsMovingUp)
        movement.y -= 1.0f;    
    if (mIsMovingDown)
        movement.y += 1.0f;
    if (mIsMovingLeft)
        movement.x -= 1.0f;
    if (mIsMovingRight)
        movement.x += 1.0f;

    mPlayer.move(movement);
}

//main file
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "game.h"

int main()
{

    Game game;
    game.run();

    return 0;
}
```

I honestly dont't even know where to begin looking for a solution.
I guess this could be driver-related, I will test it on another Computer tomorrow. 
Any advice on this would be appreciated.

**Edit in response to Ike:**
I got the SFML libraries from the Debian repository, running

```
`dpkg -l | grep sfml`
```

returns:

```
ii  libsfml-audio2:amd64                 2.1+dfsg2-1+b2                  
ii  libsfml-dev:amd64                    2.1+dfsg2-1+b2                       
ii  libsfml-graphics2:amd64              2.1+dfsg2-1+b2                       
ii  libsfml-network2:amd64               2.1+dfsg2-1+b2                       
ii  libsfml-system2:amd64                2.1+dfsg2-1+b2                       
ii  libsfml-window2:amd64                2.1+dfsg2-1+b2
```

I compiled the code above with g++ using the -O2 flag. 
I can't imagine that this is an optimization problem since the game-loop seems to go through maybe two dozen iterations per second (at most). I can't say this for certain but I believe that number should be in the thousands.

**Another Edit:** Alright, so I've compiled the same code in an Ubuntu-VM again using the repo-libraries. The circle now moves reasonably fast which is better than nothing I guess (and also suggest some issue with debian, possibly driver-related?). On another Computer (which is admittedly faster than my laptop) running arch and using sfml 2.3.2 the program runs easily ten times as fast

Comment: Did you resolve this fully in the end? I do not have the skip problem you have but movement seems slow and clunky to me.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try:

A) Set `mWindow.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false)`. This will disable auto-repeat.

B) Try changing your `Game::processEvents` to use an `if` instead of a `while`, like so:

```
void Game::processEvents()
{
    sf::Event event;
    if (mWindow.pollEvent(event))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I suspect you're seeing is the result of the event queue being spammed with auto-repeating key events. This will then cut into the frequency at which functions like `update` and `render` are being called and destroy the smooth frame rate.

The first suggestion tries to eliminate this potential of jamming up the queue. The second would make it so updates/refreshes are interleaved in between event processing and not only performed when the event queue becomes empty.

Comment: Disabling key repeat solved part of the problem, Thanks! (I'm kind of baffled that the book doesn't even mention this, maybe I've overlooked it somehow).
Still, making both corrections, the circle moves pretty slowly (albeit more regularly as well), which to my understanding is not quite right since there is no mechanism to cap the framerate or the circles speed.

Comment: Glad it helped a bit. Now it seems we have just a general speed issue. Just as a sanity check (hope it's not an offensive question), the code and lib are all being built with optimizations on?

Comment: Eeh gross -- "two dozen iterations per second". I must admit, I never used SFML -- I based my answer on just general understanding of event processing and how it's often applied in game loops. But to get to the heart of why you're getting so few iterations out of it might require someone with a lot more specific knowledge of the APIs.

Comment: But yeah, something is seriously wrong there if you only get that much out of a simple program drawing a circle to the screen.

Comment: I'll try installing the current stable version (2.3.2) now, I guess I should have done that right away, but I figured the repo-version would work fine for some quick testing

Comment: Good luck -- I'll see if I can browse through the SFML docs and spot something in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from my related question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185873/sfml-test-app-feels-slow-clunky/185880#185880 the issue could be that you were using keyboard *events* rather than real-time keyboard input.
i.e. `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed`

See https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-inputs.php